# How do I use bitwise shifts with cout?

Tags: c++, bit-shift, cout

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << 1 << 5 << std::endl;
}
```

I expect 32 (1 shifted left by 5), but I get 15.

I am trying to use a macro like this:

```
#define BIT_SHIFT(x,y) x << y
...
cout << BIT_SHIFT(1, 5) << std::endl;
```

and this happens.

Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: Parentheses? Separate variable?

Comment: You may want to improve your coding and use `inline` functions instead of macros.  You have encountered one of the major issues with using macros.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't think `inline` functions work unless you have optimizations enabled.

Comment: Inline functions work regardless of the optimization levels.  The keyword `inline` is a suggestion (recommendation) to the compiler.  Most of the compilers I've worked with honor the `inline` suggestion.  Basically, a function prefixed with the `inline` keyword.

Comment: @JL2210 -- inline functions "work" just fine, regardless of optimization settings. If they don't get inlined they are still functions, and get called as functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use parentheses:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << (1 << 5) << std::endl;
}
```

`std::cout << 1 << 5` means "push to output stream first integer literal `1`, followed by integer `5`". However, adding parantheses changes the order of evaluation, and `1 << 5` is evaluated first, resulting in `std::cout << 32 << std::endl;` expression.

Comment: Formally, it's not order of evaluation; it's **grouping** (sometimes informally referred to as "associativity", but that's not what the language definition calls it). The `<<` operator groups left to right, so `std::cout << 1 << 5;` is treated as `(std::cout << 1) << 5;`. Since the stream operator `<<` returns the stream object, the second `<<` is, essentially, `std::cout << 5`. By adding parentheses you override that grouping, so you get `1 << 5` and that's what gets inserted into the stream. +1.

Answer (score 5):

Use parenthesis:

```
    std::cout << (1 << 5) << std::endl;
```

The reason is that the output `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const T&)` overload chains the return values to call the function once more.

If you use parenthesis, the bitshift value is calculated first, and then passed to the overloaded output operator.

---

> I am trying to use this in a macro: ...

Thus the above said your macro definition should look like:

```
#define BIT_SHIFT(x,y) ((x) << (y))
```

You may wonder why the extra parenthesis now. This is just safer writing macros. Think about someone tries to use your macro like:

```
 cout << BIT_SHIFT(1, 5*2) << std::endl;
```

Comment: I usually do that. It must've slipped my mind this time. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to do something similar to this:
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
>
> int main()
> {
>    std::cout << 1 << 5 << std::endl;
> }
> ```

You're right. You are trying to do something similar to that. However, the problem has nothing to do with the macro (I mean, that's a problem too, but more on that later). The problem is your goal isn't what you mean. You don't mean `std::cout << 1 << 5 << std::endl;`, you mean `std::cout << (1 << 5) << std::endl;` The difference is that the first breaks down into something like this:

```
std::cout << 1;
std::cout << 5;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

While what you want is something like this:

```
int i = 1 << 5;

std::cout << i;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Or something to that effect.

The answer is simple: either use parenthesis in your `cout` statement, or put it in your macro (the better option):

```
// either 
cout << (BIT_SHIFT(1, 5)) << std::endl;
// or
#define BIT_SHIFT(x,y) (x << y)
...
cout << BIT_SHIFT(1, 5) << std::endl;
```

Also, as someone else suggested, you can even go a step further if you like and do this:

```
#define BIT_SHIFT(x,y) ((x) << (y))
...
cout << BIT_SHIFT(1, 5) << std::endl;
```

That way, if you do something weird in `x` or `y`, your code doesn't break.